# Running jackd on startup / replacing PulseAudio

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, jack

How can I replace PulseAudio with Jack? I want to start jackd on startup either during boot or during logon instead of PulseAudio.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add it to your start-up applications but maybe that's not very good idea as not all audio applications support jack. To make things easier there exist programs for managing and starting jack, and I think that is recommended way to use it. At least untill you get familiar with jack, and don't need assistance

So instead just launching it on start-up you could install `QjackCtl` or `Patchage`, and start and control various aspects of jack

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to replace pulseaudio. You can configure pulseaudio to redirect everything to jack. With his method, all applications which use pulse continue to work. At least this is what works for me on 12.10: [Running PulseAudio on top of JACK](https://github.com/jackaudio/jackaudio.github.com/wiki/WalkThrough_User_PulseOnJack)

In section 'Redirecting PulseAudio to JACK'

After installing the necessary pulseaudio module

```
apt-get install pulseaudio-module-jack
```

I performed the following changes to the files in /etc/pulse:

```
diff --git a/pulse/daemon.conf b/pulse/daemon.conf
index b4e8e86..2ef0b43 100644
--- a/pulse/daemon.conf
+++ b/pulse/daemon.conf
@@ -85,3 +85,18 @@ default-fragment-size-msec = 10
 ; enable-deferred-volume = yes
 deferred-volume-safety-margin-usec = 1
 ; deferred-volume-extra-delay-usec = 0
+
+; 
+; JACK REDIRECTION
+;
+; redirect all pulseaudio output to jack
+;
+; http://trac.jackaudio.org/wiki/WalkThrough/User/PulseOnJack
+;
+
+default-sample-format = float32le
+default-sample-rate = 48000
+realtime-scheduling = yes
+exit-idle-time = -1
+
+; JACK REDIRECTION END
diff --git a/pulse/default.pa b/pulse/default.pa
index 6b54ebb..cb9490d 100644
--- a/pulse/default.pa
+++ b/pulse/default.pa
@@ -163,3 +163,34 @@ load-module module-switch-on-port-available
 ### Make some devices default
 #set-default-sink output
 #set-default-source input
+
+
+# JACK REDIRECTION
+#
+# redirect all pulseaudio output to jack
+#
+# http://trac.jackaudio.org/wiki/WalkThrough/User/PulseOnJack
+#
+# the commented lines are modules which are already loaded by
+# the code above
+#
+
+# apt-get install pulseaudio-module-jack installs both source and
+#  sink modules
+
+.ifexists module-jack-sink.so
+load-module module-jack-sink channels=2
+set-default-source jack_in
+.endif
+
+# load-module module-native-protocol-unix
+# load-module module-stream-restore
+# load-module module-rescue-streams
+# load-module module-always-sink
+# load-module module-suspend-on-idle
+
+# JACK REDIRECTION END
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Your liki wink is 404 now

Comment: The link isn't 404. It is also archived for anyone 4 years in the future.